# How to monitor an SQL Server Agent Job that runs after being triggered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job

I'm running SQL Server 2008 and I have 3 agent jobs set up to run one after the other because the success of the second depends on the first, etc.

Every other job I have is independent and I monitor using a script that incorporates `MSDB..sysjobhistory run_status` field, among others.

I want to know if there is a way to specifically find all jobs that never started for a specific day. I know that I can think of the problem the other way and say job 2 couldn't possibly run if job 1 failed; however, I'm looking for a more general purpose solution so in case I need to create other jobs that are linked similarly I won't have to hard code more logic into my nightly report.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Is it too cumbersome to set them up as steps within a single job?  That way "job2" won't even try to run if "job1" fails, and you'll know if any failed because they have a failed status.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg In this case, I wish it were that simple. My first job has some Java code that needs to execute too and my second cannot begin until both the SQL and Java are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MSDB..sysjobservers` table holds a single record for every agent job in your server, and includes the field `last_run_date` which makes it easy to tell which jobs haven't run in the last 24 hours. My query looks something like this

```
SELECT A.name               AS [Name]
      ,@@servername         AS [Server]
      ,'Yes'                AS [Critical]
FROM MSDB.dbo.sysjobs A
INNER JOIN MSDB.dbo.sysjobservers B ON A.job_id = B.job_id
WHERE A.name LIKE '2%SPRING%'
      AND DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8),B.last_run_date)), GETDATE( )) > 1)
```